# Getting lots of metadata from Spotify

Tags: python, web-scraping, spotify

I'm working on a project where I have to get as much metadata from Spotify as possible. Im using the following url to get the data:
url = 'http://api.spotify.com/v1/searchquery='+letter+'&type=track,album,artist&offset='+str(pageNo)+'&limit=50'

Where 'letter' is the start letter of the tracks/artists/albums I want data from, and 'pageNo' is the index of the offset. When I do such a call, and convert the data to a json format as 'searchResponse' in python, I can use: 
searchResponse['tracks']['total']
to get the total number of tracks that match my search criterion finds. If I just make a search on the letter 'a', I get that the total number of tracks should be 3223366. However, when I iterate through my results, I can only get data on 100000 tracks. After that I only get empty results. So when i make my url call with an offset of 100000 I get data from 50 new tracks, but as soon as i increase the offset above 100000 I get an empty result. The same goes for the other letters.

So, how do I get metadata from more tracks than the first 100000?

Comment: You need to carefully read the Spotify API requirements & conditions & terms of use.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although I agree that you should be able to supply an offset that's greater than 100000 and that that's a technical issue that we may need to look into, I believe that having to page through more than 1000000 items is a clear indicator that the search query could be improved.

What's most important here is what Jan-Philip Gehrcke has already mentioned - you're **most likely** violating [Spotify's Terms of Use](https://developer.spotify.com/developer-terms-of-use/).

Comment: Thanks for the answers, I thought it would be something like that, but hoped someone knew a way to access the data, without violating Spotify.